# JOIN последней записи

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `offers` и `offers_problems`. Связь один (`offer`) ко многим (`offers_problems`). В `offers_problems` есть поле `offer_id` и есть `create_datetime`.

Как мне при выборке `offers` приджойнить последнюю запись (по полю `create_datetime`) из `offers_problems`?

Нужна последняя из `offer_problems` по `create_datetime`.

Comment: ..left join ... order by create_datetime DESC

Comment: Не понятно, что означает "последнюю запись", когда выделаете Join, у вас в операции участвуют все строки, а уже разновидность Join, выдает нужные - это первое. Второе, вы можете использовать условие WHERE для второго Join, чтобы выбрать последнюю запись из offers_problems, либо вложенный SELECT, что тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

[1] Получение последних значений *create_datetime* для каждого *offer_id*:

```
SELECT offer_id, max(create_datetime) as max_time
FROM offers_problems
GROUP BY offer_id
```

[2] Получение id'ов записей из *offers_problems* с последними *create_datetime*:

```
SELECT op.id
FROM offers_problems op JOIN ([1]) latest ON
    op.offer_id = latest.offer_id
    AND op.create_datetime = latest.max_time
```

[3] Результат:

```
SELECT *
FROM offers JOIN offers_problems op ON offers.id = op.offer_id
WHERE op.id IN ([2])
```

Итоговый запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM offers JOIN offers_problems op ON offers.id = op.offer_id
WHERE op.id IN
    (
    SELECT op.id
    FROM offers_problems op JOIN
        (
        SELECT offer_id, max(create_datetime) as max_time
        FROM offers_problems
        GROUP BY offer_id
        ) latest ON op.offer_id = latest.offer_id AND op.create_datetime = latest.max_time
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать предварительную выборку с сортировкой по дате, а потом из неё уже делать выборку с группировкой по offer.id.
Получится примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT o.*, p.`id` AS `problem_id`, p.`description` AS `problem_description`
    FROM `offer` o LEFT JOIN offer_problems` p ON p.`offer_id`=o.`id`
    ORDER BY p.`create_datetime` DESC
) tmp
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: Такой запрос вообще сработает? Вы делаете `GROUP BY id`, а выводите `SELECT *`! Что по-вашему должен вернуть такой запрос?

Comment: Да, это рабочий запрос. Вложенный запрос - это по сути временная таблица, в которой будут поля из offer и пара полей из offer_problems. Внешний запрос SELECT * - это выборка всех столбцов, сформированных вложенным запросом. Я проверил этот запрос в своей базе на примере товаров и отзывов к ним - он выдаёт товары с последним отзывом

Comment: Интересно. Только что прочитал об этом. Это будет работать при отключенном режиме ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Но это не "чистый" SQL...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM offers
INNER JOIN offers_problems
ON offers.id=offers_problems.offer_id 
ORDER BY create_datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```